# Can't log in to my Stack Overflow account after friend used my computer

Tags: support, openid, login

Earlier today, a friend of mine tried logging in to his account on my computer, but no matter what we did we got into my account instead. He's using a Technorati account, we got to the page and everything, logged in, but at Stack Overflow we ended up on mine.

I cleared all cookies and everything, but now I can't log in to my account instead.  I use a Google account.  When I try to login, I get to the Gmail login, I enter my mail and password, and get back to Stack Overflow which recognizes it as a new one.  I tried logging in again, this time I don't get the gmail login.  Instead, Stack Overflow immediately recognizes it as a new one.  If I clear all cookies and try to login using Google, I get to the Gmail login again, but still same thing.  I tried creating a new account when it asked if I'm a new user, and as expected I get a new account, 1 rep, and "unknown" as name.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What browser are you using? There are (or were, at least) some major glitches using gmail accounts and IE (in particular between different sites like SO/SU/SF).

By the e-mail on your MSO account I can trace *your* SO account; looks fine. Of course, it would be easier to validate if you updated your current MSO profile so I can check the names ;-p If your account is the one I think it is, there is also an AOL alternative open-id (in addition to the technorati one).

Perhaps if you could tell us your friend's account name as well... (and clarify your own)...

---

Re your update... it doesn't look like the horrigan1 account exists. It may have once, but [google sees nothing](http://www.google.com/search?q=horrigan+site:stackoverflow.com); there is no account by that name, etc. Was it a registered account? It also sounds like something very odd has happened, because the technorati login **is** associated with your account.

There is no gmail openid against the Clox account; there is technorati and aol. Are you sure you used your gmail to register this one?

Comment: (reposted) I'm using FireFox 3.5.1 I did try using IE 8.0 too though. this is the account I can't log in to: stackoverflow.com/users/147949/clox my friend is using his account at technorati like I said, it's horrigan1, and his mail is [snip]

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure I used my gmail account.
I'm not sure if horrigan1 was an registered account. I just tried logging in with my friends account, the horrigan1-account at technorati and got logged in as Clox, which is the account I had lost access to.
So yeah, something very odd has happened. That's definitely not what I had as my openID for clox, that account didn't even exist when i created the Clox account.

So can it be fixed? I see that I can change the alternate one myself but not the main one?

Thanks

Comment: To change the main one, you swap them first

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it was a swap button, I just thought it was a button to change the alternate one. Okay so I know how to swap them, how do I change the alternate one then?

Comment: You can only change one of them (I can't remember which) - but you can swap them to change the other....

Comment: But how do you change them?
I only know how to swap

Comment: hit the "new login" button

Answer (score 2):

Email team@stackoverflow.com. They're awfully nice and will get your account shiny again.

Answer (score 2):

*Don't know if this will help but...*

I had the same problems right after I upgraded to Firefox 3.5. I was having trouble logging back into my account after someone else logged in using my system. And then I had problems staying logged in after I cleared the cookies. To make a long story short, it seemed like cookies weren't being created or updated consistently.

After twiddling with all the cookie settings for a few hours, the solution was to delete my cookie files' database. I had to make hidden files visible and delete the entire database (cookies.sqlite, in Firefox) located in C:\Documents and Settings\ *username* \Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles...

Maybe you are seeing a similar problem in your system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried what you said but it didn't help.. =\

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an old non-gmail as your google account login name and you are trying to login from a new computer. In my case, Google seems to have messed up the account and only passes the gmail address instead of the original email address to Stack Exchange, so Stack Exchange obviously thinks this is a newly created account.

Workaround, if you have a computer where the cookies still allow you to log into your Stack Overflow account: Go to your account profile and click on "my logins", then "add more logins" and associate another ID to your account, i.e. Yahoo. Now you can login to your Stack Overflow account with the new ID.