# cookies remembering openID authentication for stackoverflow, but not serverfault or superuser?

Tags: support, openid, login

Does anyone else have this problem?

I'm logged into stackoverflow, superuser, and serverfault using my openID account. If I close a tab, and visit the same site again, it maintains my logged-in state. When I restart my browser, however, I have to log into superuser and serverfault again, but stackoverflow remembers me. Is there a bug?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox 3.5 -- i'll check out the approach referenced by rcartaino below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem so see if *this* solution helps you: [Can’t log in to my stackoverflow account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12078/cant-log-in-to-my-stackoverflow-account/12080#12080).

When I upgraded to Firefox 3.5, It seemed like my browser was losing login cookies for *some* sites but not for others. It turned out to be a corrupt cookie database.

Comment: not sure if this was the problem, but it's a moot point, so i'm accepting.